# Can't install my Adhoc ios build in a specific ios Device (iPhone XS - iOS 14.2)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, adhoc, app-distribution

I tried to build and distribute couple of Adhoc distribution build with bit code and without bitcode .. and generated build on both Diawi and installonair anyway the link installed on 2 devices without any problems. 1. iphone x - ios 14.1 and iPhone 6s - ios 14.2 but it's not installing on my manager's  iPhone xs - iOS 14.2 :(.  I am receiving following message on his phone "Unable to install - This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified. I think this problem happens only after I updated to Xcode 12.2 and I am still running on macOS catalina version 10.15.7.

[image: screen shot from iPhone Xs - ios 14.1]

Comment: Are you using a developer cert/profile part of a paid developer program?

Comment: @satheesh yes I am using a paid developer account for an organization.. we have renewed recently

Comment: Hmmm that gives me some doubts..
Is the device mapped to the profile correctly?
can you go to settings->profiles and see whether anything has to be approved? Also restart your device once & make sure the date/time on the device is correct as per the timezone.

Comment: It's not working bro.. tried everything.. only on his device

Comment: I have the same problem. It's started today. The app worked great last year. My single developer certificated expired a week ago, and I've renew it yesterday. Today I was needed to install the app, and now have this error. I've tried a lot of things, without success.

Comment: error on IPhone 7 - ios 14.2. using macOS catalina version 10.15.7. xcode v.12.2

Comment: @Kherel I also tried lot of solutions during past 2 days still no success. I switched to new distribution certificate and new bundle identifier but still not got the iphone xs device to test which is the problem for me. Let me know if you found any solutions..

Comment: @Kherel Remove anything you have in embedded framework and archive it again, It worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove anything you have in embedded framework and archive it again, It worked for me. I had Pods framework of my own project that generated by automatically after I removed that and archive again it worked. And also I used fresh distribution certificate and bundle identifier. Hope it will helps for some developers.

Comment: `Remove anything you have in embedded framework`
This helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problems.

Enterprise app:

- installing smoothly from the current server.
- Change the server and some user-facing this problem.

Solving methods:

- Update the version number of the app.
- Change the build number of the app.

Its working fine.